# Refresh the Fragment on dismiss of Dialogue fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

There is some synch process on server that updates the database and I want to refresh the parent activity on click of dialogue dismiss to get the synched values in a view.

I have three fragments- `FragmentA.java`, `FragmentB.java` and `ragmentC.java`

In `FragmentA.java`, I have public interface `OnEntrySelectedListener` which have method `getDialog()` and 
other fragment class `FragmentB.java` implements this interface and have definition for `getDialog()` method.

**FragmentA.java**

```
class FragmentA extends Fragment
{
  public interface OnEntrySelectedListener
  {
    getDialog();
  }
}
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
 class FragmentB extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentA.OnEntrySelectedListener
   {
     @Override
    public void getDialog(Bundle bundle) {
        FragmentC cf = new FragmentC(); 
        cf.setArguments(bundle);
        cf.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
        }
    }
```

**FragmentC.java**

```
class FragmentC extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //some code here
        }

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shared,container, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
          getDialog().dismiss(); //Here after dismiss, I want to refresh FragmentA
         }
     });
         return view;


 }
```

Now I want to refresh the `FragmentA` on dismiss of `FragmentC`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an interface and callback to C to do something like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof Dismissed) {
      ((Dismissed) getActivity()).dialogDismissed();
    }
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
  }

  public interface Dismissed {
    public void dialogDismissed();
  }
```

Then in the main activity you can implement the interface and when you get the call you forward it to fragment A.

You could also fire a refresh event that FragmentA would listen to.

Comment: After implementing this interface in mainactivity, how will I get a call in this mainactivity?

Comment: The code I added should be in the dialogfragment. If the main activity, the activity holding fragment C, implements the Dismissed interface, it will get a call on the dialogDismissed method when the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: The call some function in A on the dismiss. In the activity's dialogDismissed() do fragmentA.refresh()

Comment: The method refresh() is undefined for the type FragmentA.

Comment: Then create it and refresh the fragment in it, or am I missing something?

Comment: created the method refresh but how to refresh the fragment in it?

Comment: Depends on what kind of refresh you want? do you want a redraw you can use invalidate, or do you want to reget data, then do that.