# Listen DialogFragment dismiss event from ViewPager Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

There are lot of (duplicate) questions and answers are available, I went through almost all of them and failed. On reference of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619065/refresh-the-fragment-on-dismiss-of-dialogue-fragment) question, I made some changes recently.

Brief : In my app, MainActivity holds Fragment View Pager and  FrangmentA,B and C. FrangmentA Shows a DialogFragment CDialog onClik. After dismissing CDialog I need to Call FragmentA's doReload() which is not happening here.

MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                          ...

            mSectionsPageAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
            setupViewPager(mViewPager);
            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
            int defaultValue = 0;
            int page = getIntent().getIntExtra("One", defaultValue);
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
        {
            FragmentAdapter adapter = new 
            FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new FragmentA(), "FragA");
            adapter.addFragment(new FragmentB(), "FragB");
            adapter.addFragment(new FragmentC(), "FragC");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

FragmentA

```
    public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements CDialog.Dismissed{
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   FragmentManager fm =  getActivity().getFragmentManager();
                    DialogFragment f = new CDialog();
                    f.show(fm, "CDialog");
                    }
            });

 @Override
    public void dialogDismissed() {
        Log.e(DFD_1, "dialogDismiss Called" );// <-- This is not working*
        doReload();
    }
    }
```

And CDialogue

```
public  class CDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                    ....
                      return v;
   }
  @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           ...

            dfd_1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                        getDialog().dismiss(); //<--when this happens*
                    }
            });

}
    @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
            if (getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof Dismissed) {
                ((Dismissed) getActivity()).dialogDismissed();
            }
            super.onDismiss(dialog);
        }

        public interface Dismissed {
            public void dialogDismissed();  //<-- FragmentA implements this 
        }
}
```

Comment: In CDialog's onDismiss() it seems you trigger the Dismissed callback on your Activity and not your fragment A. So either get a reference to the fragment on which you want to call doReload or keep the current implementation but make the Activity call the doReleaod method on fragment A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always have direct callback to your Fragment itself.

First step, is to set targetFragment using `setTargetFragment()`:

```
DialogFragment#setTargetFragment(Fragment fragment, int requestCode);
```

I do it this way:

```
public void showDialogFragment(Fragment targetFragment, AppCompatDialogFragment appCompatDialogFragment, int requestCode) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    appCompatDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(targetFragment, requestCode);
    fragmentTransaction.add(appCompatDialogFragment, appCompatDialogFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

and then call to this method to open dialog fragment as:

```
public static final int RC_CDIALOG = 111;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
               showDialogFragment(FragmentA.this, new CDialog(), RC_CDIALOG);
            }
        });
```

Then, in your DialogFragment's `onDismissListener()`, have some code like below:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);

    if (getTargetFragment() instanceof FragmentA)
        ((FragmentA) getTargetFragment()).doReload();

}
```

**What you did this way is:**

Show Dialog Fragment "CDialog" along with telling it that your target fragment is "FragmentA" whose reference you can use incase you have something to do with it. In your case you had to call `doReload();`